# Linq DataContext.ExecuteCommand and SaveChanges

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am currently reading some code which make use of `DataContect.ExecuteCommand` in LinqToSQL.

My main concern is when the changes of this `ExecuteCommand` happen on the db. Do the happen as soon as I call `ExecuteCommand` or when I do a `SaveChanges`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you call that method, it will directly happend and will execute the command against the database, from the docs for [`ExecuteCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Executes SQL commands directly on the database.

Therefor you shouldn't use `SaveChanges()` with `ExecuteCommand` method, because `ExecuteCommand` is used as an alternative for `SaveChanges()` in cases you want to execute a command directly to the database. For example:

```
int result = DatabaseContext.ExecuteCommand("delete from blahblah = {0}", entity.Id));
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed to know.